# Flask + Bokeh Server on Azure Web App Service

Tags: azure, flask, bokeh, azure-web-app-service

I want to host my bokeh server app in Azure Web App Services. Following the example in [flask_embed.py](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/howto/server_embed/flask_embed.py) I created a minimal example with a bokeh server process running on localhost:5006 and serving it with `server_document` in a flask route. Locally, in my computer, it runs normally without any errors:

```py
from threading import Thread

from bokeh.embed import server_document
from bokeh.server.server import Server
from bokeh.models.widgets import Select, Div
from bokeh.layouts import column

from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop

app = Flask(__name__)

# This is the bokeh page
def modify_doc(doc):
    dropdown = Select(title="Cities", options=["New York", "Berlin"])
    title_row = Div(text="Home Page")

    main_layout = column([
        title_row,
        dropdown
    ])

    doc.add_root(main_layout)
    doc.title = "My bokeh server app"

# This is the subprocess serving the bokeh page
def bk_worker():
    server = Server(
        {'/bkapp': modify_doc},
        io_loop=IOLoop(),
        allow_websocket_origin=["*"],
    )
    server.start()
    server.io_loop.start()


Thread(target=bk_worker).start()

# This is the flask route showing the bokeh page
@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def my_app():
    script = server_document("http://localhost:5006/bkapp")
    return render_template("embed.html", script=script, template="Flask")
```

However, when I push it to the Azure web app, the page is blank and by inspecting the page an error message is shown:

```
GET https://<my-azure-site>.azurewebsites.net:5006/bkapp/autoload.js?bokeh-autoload-element=0bfb1475-9ddb-4af5-9afe-f0c4a681d7aa&bokeh-app-path=/bkapp&bokeh-absolute-url=https://<my-azure-site>.azurewebsites.net:5006/bkapp net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

It seems like I don't have access to the localhost of the remote Azure server. Actually, it's not yet clear to me if the bokeh server runs/is allowed to run at all. In the `server_document` function I have tried putting `server_document("<my-azure-site>:5006/bkapp")` but the problem remains the same.

Any help is appreciated.

*This post is related to another question: [Bokeh embedded in flask app in azure web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51512775/bokeh-embedded-in-flask-app-in-azure-web-app])*

Comment: The related question you linked does not exist any more. Did you (or somebody else reading this) ever find a solution?

Comment: Did you find any solution here?

Answer (score 3):

I realize this is from a while ago, but I've spent many hours in the past several days figuring this out, so this is for future people:

---

The issue is that server_document() is just creating a `<script>` tag that gets embedded into a jinja2 template, where it executes.

Locally it's not an issue because your bokeh server is running on YOUR MACHINE'S localhost:5006. To demonstrate, you can see that you can navigate directly to localhost:5006/bkapp to see your bokeh document.

Once you're hosting it on Azure, server_document() is creating the exact same script that a browser will try to execute - that is, your browser is going to try to execute a `<script>` tag that references localhost:5006, except that there isn't anything running on localhost:5006 because your bokeh app is actually running on Azure's server now.

I'm not sure what the best way to do it is, but the essence of it is that you need server_document() to point to the bokeh server that's running remotely. To do this you'll need to make sure that {your_remote_bokeh_server}:5006 is publicly accessible.